# How can map an asp.net MVC route with more than 3 components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to learn asp.net mvc, and almost everywhere I see route description with three components like /Controller/Action/{anyParams}
I'd like to know if I can map a route similar to,

`/Folder(or namespace)/Controller/Action/params...`
ex:

```
    /Admin/Student/Edit/id
    /ABC/Faculty/Add/`
    /XYZ/Student/Edit/id
```

or in general, 
`/XYZ/Controller1/Action/{param}`

Answer (score 1):

Yep the second parameter in the MapRoutes function (usually in Global.asax.cs is Url and this can be any pattern you want. something like

`routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "XYZ/Controller1/Action/{param}",
new {controller = "Controller1", action = "Action"}});`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your routes as complex as you want.

F.e. the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("some-route", "products/detail/order/{id}/{name}/",
             new { controller = "Products", action = "Order" },
             new { id = "^\d+" });
```

will route to the following function:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller {
     public ActionResult Order (int id, string name) {

     }
}
```

So you can specify as many parameters as you want, and they will be passed into your action as function parameters.

Comment: what if I have two controllers with same name under two namespace/(sub)folder, how will it get mapped by the above route?